# what are the devices will be listed

Tags: c++, winapi, msdn, volume

please let me know what are the devices wil be listed using the below code

```
guid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_VOLUME;

// Get device Information handle for Volume interface
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs( &guid, NULL, NULL,
DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All devices that are present in the system that have enabled an interface from the storage volume [device interface class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff553412%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff551069%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: "Enabled"? Are you sure about that? Will it exclude devices whose SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA.Flags do not contain SPINT_ACTIVE ?

Comment: Example 4 suggests that would be the case